# interstitial won't let app launch

Tags: android, google-play-services, interstitial

I've got a problem: I'm trying to add interstitial ads in my app, I thought it would be easy because I already have conventional one and it works perfectly, but something gone wrong..

Here's my code (**in_app_billing_system**):

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
 ...
 ...
 ...
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
 mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
 AdRequest adRequestI = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("bla bla bla").build();
 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestI);
```

And here's my error:

> 08-07 10:03:00.495  13565-13565/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: ****, PID: 13565
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*****.ActMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:94)
>               at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.zza.zzP(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze.zzb(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.zzL(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
>               at ****.InAppBillingSystem.(InAppBillingSystem.java:46)
>               at ****.ActMain.onCreate(ActMain.java:59)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I tried to use original Google code from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) but the result is the same.

The code at Line 59 in Main Activity:

```
  //INSTALL APP
    if (IS_FIRST_START) tablesInit();

    if (loadFromPref("registered", "").equals("yes")) {
        is_purchased = true;
    } else {
        is_purchased = false;
 **59:    in_app_billing_system = new InAppBillingSystem(this);**
    }
```

I never used this type of ads, maybe I have missed something?

P.S. Don't be confused with name "in_app_billing_system" it's from old times and now I have no in-app but ads there.

Comment: Whats the code at line 59 in your Activity?? else post your complete code?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the line:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
```

Instead what I should have used:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(myActivity);
```

The problem has been solved.